# Laravel like model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a Eloquence like model. The Eloquence class's functions are all static but they are using a non-static $table as variable to indicate the model's class. How is that possible to use a non-static variable in a static function?

**Edit 1**: So if I understand well, the functions are actually non-static but a another function is creating a new static instance of that non-static function. So now I would like to know how to do it without using laravel?

Comment: This answer will cover what you want to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473243/php-oop-how-to-assign-not-static-property-to-static-method/24481967#24481967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, Eloquent proxies class methods to instance methods.

**Example:**

```
class Model {
    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments) 
    {
        // create an instance of this model
        $instance = new static; 

        // dynamically call instance method, with the same arguments
        return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $arguments);
    }
}
```

Take a look at real [Eloquent\Model](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/6b3c1ccd780124a56a854bc4a6e4d4d087b9dfe4/Eloquent/Model.php#L3034-L3046) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You said `The Eloquence class's functions are all static` but it's not true. Instead it uses a static style method calls and it's been possible because of Laravel's `Facade` classes.

> **Taken From Laravel's Documentation:**
>
> Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in
>   the application's IoC container. Laravel ships with many facades, and
>   you have probably been using them without even knowing it! Laravel
>   "facades" serve as "static proxies" to underlying classes in the IoC
>   container, providing the benefit of a terse, expressive syntax while
>   maintaining more testability and flexibility than traditional static
>   methods.

Your asked `How is that possible to use a non-static variable in a static function?` Hope you got the answer. To get more clear idea, read the [explanation](http://laravel.com/docs/facades) on `Laravel`'s website.